# Is it possible to setup a clean user account, as if it's a new OSX install?

Tags: macos

Wondering if it's possible to setup a new user account so that it has no access to the applications installed on my main(default) account (/Application). I would like to create and configure as if it's a new OSX install.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All users share acces to /Applications.

Move apps you want restricted to your user's home folder ~/Applications and then creat a new user from system preferences.